# ParseHexBinary being fooled by string?

Tags: java, hex

Hello i'm working on some code and i found something funny. So i have this string in binary encoded in hexadecimal which is called hexBinary. My info from the DB is in this format but there are some data that is still in plain text, which is not a problem since when i do a:

```
return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s)
```

It will either return the bytes[] or throw an exception if the input wasn't a hexBinary, but this mechanism is being "fooled" by a string that i used for testing which it was "aaaa" which will give me issues later.

Why does this string is  being parsed as a hexBinary and other plain text strings like "depp" that i used are not being converted to bytes[] (which i actually don't want if they are just plain text)

What i have as a hex binary is this for example: B3ABE2E0F609C1CC5D63CE5A1DA1708E

Is there any kind of regex or validator that i could use to avoid dealing with IllegalArgumentExceptions if it's just plain text?

All the info coming out from the Db is coming as a String

Comment: Perhaps the hex binary format is described in your database documentation?

Comment: Letters a though f can be used as binary digits, so `aaaa` is a perfect binary number (worth 43690). Letter p cannot, so `depp` is invalid, hence the exception.

Comment: "aaaa" is a valid hexadecimal string. "depp" isn't.

Comment: OHHHHH didn't know that, although that is something remotely to happen, is there any way to avoid something like that?

Comment: or even know what is plain text like a name, and what is a hex like the one i put up as a example, to have a validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hexadecimal number means a number in base 16. Since 16 distinct digits are needed for writing such anumber, it consists of digits 0 through 9 and letters a through f (for digits 10 through 15). You can see for yourself that your example, `B3ABE2E0F609C1CC5D63CE5A1DA1708E`, is a hexadecimal number by this definition. The letters may be uppercase or lowercase, it doesn’t matter and doesn’t make any difference.

So `aaaa` is a perfect hexadecimal number. Its decimal equivalent is 43690.

So if you get `aaaa` or a word consisting of only letters a–f like `dad`, `beef`, `deaf`, `cafe`, `dead`, `feed`, `babe` or `faded`, you really haven’t got any way to tell whether this was intended as a hexadecimal number or it was a word from a different context being transmitted to you by mistake. The parsing you are already doing is the standard validation that one would do in your situation. So you may consider living with it.

If you want a still stricter validation without rejecting good-faith hexadecimal numbers, a couple of ideas are:

1. If you know that your hexadecimal numbers always have the letters A–F in uppercase, reject any input that contains a lower-case letter.
2. If you know that your hexadecimal number always has a certain length or a certain minimum length, reject input strings that are shorter.

Link: [Hexadecimal Numbers](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/binary/bin_3.html)

Comment: That's great, thanks everyone and you for the feedback.